# Autofac Circular Dependency With Enumeration

Tags: c#, autofac

I have some code of the following form:

```
class DependsOnEnumerations : IDependsOnEnumerations{
  IEnumerable<IDependsOnEnumerator> dependencies;
}
...
interface IDependsOnEnumerator{
}
...
class DependencyA: IDependsOnEnumerator{
  IDependsOnEnumerations dependency;
}
...
class DependencyB: IDependsOnEnumerator{
  IDependsOnEnumerations dependency;
}
...
```

I would like to use Autofac to properly resolve this dependency, which is circular and has an enumeration.

What I've tried so far is declaring both sets of dependencies as properties:

```
class DependsOnEnumerations : IDependsOnEnumerations{
  internal IEnumerable<IDependsOnEnumerator> dependencies { get; set;}
}
...
class DependencyA: IDependsOnEnumerator{
  internal IDependsOnEnumerations dependency {get; set;}
}
...
```

and then registering in Autofac with

```
builder.registerType<DependsOnEnumerations>
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope()
.PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
builder.registerType<DependencyA>
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.SingleInstance()
.PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
builder.registerType<DependencyB>
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.SingleInstance()
.PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
...
```

and what happens here is that DependencyA and DependencyB tell me that their dependency is null.

I've also tried declaring only one of them as a property:

```
class DependsOnEnumerations : IDependsOnEnumerations{
  private readonly IEnumerable<IDependsOnEnumerator> _dependencies;

  internal DependsOnEnumerations(IEnumerable<IDependsOnEnumerator> dependencies){
    _dependencies = dependencies;
  }
}
...
class DependencyA: IDependsOnEnumerator{
  internal IDependsOnEnumerations dependency {get; set;}
}
...
```

or

```
class DependsOnEnumerations : IDependsOnEnumerations{
  internal IEnumerable<IDependsOnEnumerator> dependencies { get; set;}
}
...
class DependencyA: IDependsOnEnumerator{
  private readonly IDependsOnEnumerations _dependency;

  internal DependencyA(IDependsOnEnumerations dependency){
    _dependency = dependency;
  }
}
...
```

What happens is that in the first case, the enumerable is null, and in the second case, the dependency is null; ie whatever is made a property seems not to be resolved properly. I'm a bit at a loss how I can get this dependency resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertiesAutowired` method requires a `Public` setter property.

```
class DependencyA: IDependsOnEnumerator{
  public IDependsOnEnumerations dependency {get; set;}
}
```

You can see it on the [DefaultPropertySelector.cs](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/5a6b790114dab4da141243abc6d39cab3f9024d8/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/DefaultPropertySelector.cs) source code (Line 48)

---

By the way you should really refactor your design to avoid circular dependency. Such dependency will make your code more difficult to understand. If both components needs each other it may be more simple to merge these components or create a third one to break this circular dependency.